# How to deserializer two Models in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, serialization, httpresponse

[image]
i'm sending two serializer models to api.py file... it is sending successfully but how to de-serializer both models in api.py

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, response
from api.serializer import ResultsDNSerializer, ClassesExamMaxMarksSerializer, ResultSerializer, BlogPostsSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer


def ShowStudentResultAPI(request, id,eid):

    # Here id is Unique id of ResultDelcareNotice's Model and eid is ePunjabID of student
    Result_Delcare_Data =   ResultsDeclareNotice.objects.filter(ID=id).first()    
    Get_SessionCode     =   Result_Delcare_Data.SessionCode
    Get_AnnResultCode   =   Result_Delcare_Data.AnnResultCode
    Get_MonthCode       =   Result_Delcare_Data.MonthCode
    
           
    # Here AnnualResults is Model and here just we are fetching data
    stu_Data            =   AnnualResults.objects.get(SessionCode=Get_SessionCode,AnnResultCode=Get_AnnResultCode,MonthCode=Get_MonthCode,EID=eid)

    ResultDataTerm1     =   AnnualResults.objects.filter(SessionCode=Get_SessionCode,AnnResultCode=Get_AnnResultCode,MonthCode=Get_MonthCode,EID=eid).first()
    StudentClassTerm1   =   ResultDataTerm1.ClassCode                    

    Class_MaxMarksData  =   ClassesExamMaxMarks.objects.get(SessionCode=Get_SessionCode, ClassCode=StudentClassTerm1,AnnResultCode=Get_AnnResultCode)
    
    serializer          =   ResultSerializer(stu_Data)    
    json_data           =   JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)

    serializer_class_marks  =   ClassesExamMaxMarksSerializer(Class_MaxMarksData)
    json_data_class_marks   =   JSONRenderer().render(serializer_class_marks.data)

    Serializer_list = [json_data, json_data_class_marks]
        
    return HttpResponse(Serializer_list)
```

api.py

```
import requests

URL =   "http://localhost:8000/api/result/1/4474239/"

req =   requests.get(url = URL)

data=   req.json()
print(data)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you mean "both models"? There are multiple models in your code.

Please, try to prepare minimal reproducible example according to this tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: 1) AnnualResults 2) ClassesExamMaxMarks

Comment: Read a little bit about nested serializers: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships